# Does JPA2 have a replacement for EclipseLinks @JoinFetch(@JoinFetchType.INNER)?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have following code that uses EclipseLinks [@JoinFetch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Common_Relationship_Configurations/JoinFetch) annotation. Is it possible use JPA2 annotation to do the same thing or do I have to rely on JPA provider specific annotations?

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", nullable = false)
@JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.INNER)
@Override
public Something getSomething() {
    return this.something;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2.0 does not define any standard annotation for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is way to specify join type of collections with annotations in JPA. You can explicitly specify [JoinType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/JoinType.html) while [fetching](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html#fetch%28java.lang.String,%20javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType%29) or [joining](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join%28java.lang.String,%20javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType%29) a collection:

```
Root<Entity> entity = cq.from(Entity.class);
entity.fetch(entity.get("children"), JoinType.RIGHT);
//or
entity.join(entity.get("children"), JoinType.LEFT);
```